# Como selecionar Python 3 no Visual code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Já instalei a extensão do Python no VSCode mas quero saber como faço para ele reconhecer a sintase do Python 3?

Comment: Síntese? Ou sintaxe?

Comment: Existem mais de uma extensão do VS code disponíveis Felipe, pode indicar qual você está usando?

Comment: @gmsantos estou usando a python, que está em recomendada

Comment: Qual o nome do autor da extensão? Don Jayamanne? Preciso saber exatamente qual é a extensão pois a configuração varia entre elas.

Comment: @gmsantos  sim, a de Don Jayamanne

Answer (score 1):

Em alguns casos, o problema pode estar no Python corrente do VS Code. Para alterá-lo, basta clicar na versão corrente do Python no canto inferior esquerdo do Vs Code:

[image: Versão corrente do Python]

Em seguida, selecione a versão desejada:

[image: Menu de seleção do VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

Abra os Settings e adicione a seguinte chave:

```
"pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
```

Mas a forma correta mesmo seria você ir até a pasta do seu projeto, criar um virtualenv assim:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 venv
```

ativar o virtual env

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

e então dar o comando

```
code .
```

assim o visual studio code vai abrir todos os arquivos dessa pasta usando o python do virtualenv como interpretador.